# Sens d'origine de "pourboire"

Tags: sens, étymologie, histoire

I just learned this word today and, at first glance, the etymology seems obvious: the original meaning being *quelque chose **pour boire*** (alcohol, presumably).

However, after searching in the [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/pourboire), [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/pourboire), and [Académie 8ème édition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/pourboire), nothing useful comes up concerning the original sense of the word - just that it comes from *pour boire* (my original assumption).

What was the *original usage* of the word? Does it have the same semantic meaning as I assume (a recompense for those who provide a service, so that they could drink alcohol)?

---

Je viens d'apprendre ce mot aujourd'hui et, à première vue, l'étymologie me semble claire : le sens d'origine étant *quelque chose **pour boire*** (probablement de l'alcool).

Cependant, après avoir cherché dans le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/pourboire), [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/pourboire), et [Académie 8ème édition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/pourboire), je ne trouve rien d'utile concernant le sens d'origine du mot - seulement qu'il vient de *pour boire* (mon hypothèse originale).

Quel est *l'usage original* du mot ? A-t-il le même sens sémantique que je suppose (une récompense pour ceux qui fournissent un service, afin qu'ils puissent boire [de l'alcool])?

Comment: @Laure Et bien je ne suis pas très fort ni en histoire ni en littérature :) je crois le sens original du mot d'être un peu d'argent donné pour boire de l'alcool, mais je ne suis pas sûr de ce fait, et donc je voulais une référence de qualité pour confirmer. Il me semble qu'il y a une petite histoire autour de ce mot, que je voulais révéler. Les références que j'ai citées ne me sont pas très claires à cet égard, donné que je ne connais pas l'histoire que vous venez de me raconter :)

Comment: @Laure Je pense que oui!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comme signalé dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/pourboire) (et confirmé par le *[Dictionnaire culturel en langue française](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence:Dictionnaire_culturel_en_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)*) la première occurrence de l'expression date de 1662 dans l'*École des femmes* de Molière (Act. IV, sc. 4) où, dans le but qu'ils intercèdent auprès d'Agnès en sa faveur, Arnolphe donne de l'argent à Alain, son valet, « pour boire », et à Georgette, sa servante, « pour s'acheter un cotillon ».

> Je ne suis pas un homme à vouloir rien pour rien,
>   Je sais quand on me sert en garder la mémoire :
>   Cependant par avance, Alain voilà pour boire,
>   Et voilà pour t’avoir, Georgette, un cotillon.
>   (Ils tendent tous deux la main, et prennent l’argent.)
>   Ce n’est de mes bienfaits qu’un simple échantillon,
>   Toute la courtoisie enfin dont je vous presse,
>   C’est que je puisse voir votre belle maîtresse.

Le parallèle est fait entre **pour s'acheter** et **pour boire**, la préposition *pour* introduisant le but est suivi d'un verbe à l'infinitif. Arnolphe donne de l'argent dans les deux cas mais en déclare la destination à ses serviteurs. Pour le bourgeois Arnolphe, la boisson ne siérait guère à une servante et dans son esprit cet argent doit être destiné à se faire belle.

L'expression a été reprise, d'abord sans, puis avec tiret, puis selon le TLF en un seul mot pour la première fois dans les Comptes de la duchesse de Mazarin en 1760 en citation dans la revue *[Rétrospective](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k203793m/f422.image)* en 1892 :

> Pour avoir donné pourboire au recardeleux de matelat 1 liv. 4 s.

Comment: Très belle réponse, merci!

Comment: Petite question: pourquoi la pratique n'est-t-elle pas attestée avant le XVIIe siècle?

Comment: @Frank  Peut-être qu'elle n'existait pas avant ? D'après wikipedia la pratique serait  apparue en Angleterre au 17e s. Ce que confirme de nombreux articles que je viens de consulter sur la pratique aux USA qui en font remonter l'origine à l'Angleterre. D'autres en français disent la même chose.  Le mot *tip* en anglais apparaît pour la première fois au 18e s.1706­-7 "*Farquhar Beaux Strat. ii. ii, Then I, Sir, tips me the Verger with half a Crown*" (OED).

Comment: La [plus ancienne référence](http://www.theasterisktoday.com/articles/bad-gratitudes-working-for-tips-since-medieval-serfdom/) que je trouve fait remonter la pratique à la fin du Moyen-âge.  Might be a question for history.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai pas trouvé de référence à ce mot antérieure au XVIIe siècle, en interrogeant les fonds de la BNF (formes "pourboire" et "pour-boire"), et google. Le mot surgit comme appelé du néant, et je n'ai pas trouvé de détails sur une coutume du *pourboire* aux alentours de l'époque à laquelle le mot est apparu. ngrams révèle que le mot est devenu plus populaire vers le début du XXe siècle.

J'ai trouvé cette [petite histoire](http://www.linternaute.com/acheter/pourboire/histoire.shtml), qui pourrait bien être apocryphe plus qu'historique, beaucoup de conseils style "guide du routard", mais personne ne semble s'intéresser au *pourquoi* de cette coutume. On peut naïvement supposer que le serviteur (forcément un *serviteur* d'une façon ou d'une autre) n'aurait su utiliser une telle petite somme que pour aller boire de l'alcool. Une explication qui évoque *L'assommoir*.

Answer (score 1):

Voici l'histoire de cette pratique:

La pratique du pourboire est bien implantée en France dès le XVIème siècle (Mazuyer, 1947), et demeure actuelle : vestige de charité si on rapproche le pourboire de l’aumône, comme c’est le cas dans plusieurs définitions évoquant une « petite libéralité que l’on donne en sus du prix convenu » (Littré) ; vestige de ce paternalisme avec lequel autrefois on traitait les domestiques, dimension symbolique du rapport maître-serviteur qui transparaît dans le mot **lui-même puisqu’il s’agit de boire à la santé du maître avec la pièce donnée** 3

Aujourd’hui, la pratique existe dans tous les établissements de service. Elle concerne d’abord les salariés exerçant ce que la
coutume nomme un « métier à pourboires ». Ce sont des métiers auxquels est associé
un bas statut social en raison de la faiblesse des revenus, des conditions de travail et
du niveau d’études requis : les garçons de cafés, les serveuses et serveurs en
restaurant, les employés d’hôtel en contact avec la clientèle, les coiffeuses et
coiffeurs, les esthéticiennes, les livreurs et les chauffeurs de taxi4
. Mais tous les employés de commerce, qu’ils exercent ou non dans le domaine alimentaire, sont susceptibles de recevoir un pourboire, même si ce n’est pas de façon régulière, du garçon-boucher au loueur de chaises longues sur la plage. L’origine de la coutume, qui seule établit la distinction entre les métiers à pourboire et les autres, est difficile à déterminer : [...]

[histoire du pourboire](https://spire.sciencespo.fr/hdl:/2441/53r60a8s3kup1vc9k61bgisb6/resources/henaut-pinna.pdf)